# How to make Create React App subfolder of public autoload?

Tags: reactjs

I setup react project by create-react-app and I found that the subfolder of react won't able to autoload when I create a new file, eg

```html
<!-- file: /public/subfolder/index.html -->
<p>subfolder content here</p>
```

anyone knows how? According to the official react doc, it looks like react doesn't allow this kind pattern? Anyone knows more content?

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a restriction from React itself. That was how `Webpack` has configured in `create-react-app`. Please look at the below code snippet of a typical Webpack config file in a React application. If we need more custom configuration, we have to manually configure Webpack and Babel as per our requirements.

[image]

Link for the documentation: [The best webpack configurations for React applications](https://blog.logrocket.com/versatile-webpack-configurations-react-application/)